# where can I find "zend script file" needed by netbeans IDE?

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans

in netbeans 7.3 if I want to create a new php project using zend framework it asks to set zend script in netbeans php settings but I can't find such file although I searched in the folder that contains zend framework files please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about the "zh.sh". You have to download the FULL Package of Zend Framework [Zend Framework Download](http://framework.zend.com/downloads/latest). The FIle is located at /DownloadXX/bin. If you are on windows use zf.bat instead.

Comment: It's not there!

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans should be talking about the `index.php` file located in the `public` directory.